# How to conditionally retrieve rows from data.table in R?

Tags: r, select, row, conditional-statements, data.table

I've got a data table containing some demographic data retrieved from Eurostat (I haven't transposed the data yet; Eurostat is providing the time line as variables and the variables as observations), processed the data (basically splitting up a joint column into three separate ones, and combining historical with forecast data, resulting in a 17,070 x 1,444 data.table).

**Excerpt of demographic data**

```
require(data.table)
(DT <- data.table(
            "age"  = c("TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL"),
            "sex"  = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F"),
            "geo"  = c("AD", "AL", "AM", "AT", "AZ"),
            "2014" = c(NA,    NA,      NA,      4351253, NA),
            "2013" = c(37408, NA,      NA,      4328238, 4707690),
            "2012" = c(38252, NA,      1684000, 4309977, 4651601),
            "2011" = c(38252, 1409931, 1679066, 4296293, 4594023),
            "2010" = c(40296, NA,      1673656, 4285442, 4542083),
            key = c("age", "sex", "geo")
        ))

     age sex geo    2014    2013    2012    2011    2010
1: TOTAL   F  AD      NA   37408   38252   38252   40296
2: TOTAL   F  AL      NA      NA      NA 1409931      NA
3: TOTAL   F  AM      NA      NA 1684000 1679066 1673656
4: TOTAL   F  AT 4351253 4328238 4309977 4296293 4285442
5: TOTAL   F  AZ      NA 4707690 4651601 4594023 4542083
```

Next task is the slicing & dicing of the table in order some specific questions, eg. "What's the size of the female population in Armenia in 2012?"

I've evaluated four approaches, namely

- subsetting by logical comparison;
- subsetting facilitating %in% operator;
- row selection by logical comparison;
- row selection facilitating %in% operator.

As it turns out the latter one appears to be the one delivering the best performance (please see below the timings for corresponding example queries against the whole table).

**Example #1**

```
system.time(
    subset(DTfull, 
           (Age == "TOTAL") & 
           ((Sex == "M") | (Sex == "F")) &
           ((Region == "AT") | (Region == "DE") | (Region == "UK"))
    )
)

       user  system elapsed 
      0.069   0.000   0.069
```

**Example #2**

```
system.time(
    subset(DTfull, 
           (Age %in% c("TOTAL")) & 
           (Sex %in% c("M", "F")) & 
           (Region %in% c("AT", "DE", "UK"))
    )
)

       user  system elapsed 
      0.064   0.000   0.063
```

**Example #3**

```
system.time(
    DTfull[
        (Age == "TOTAL") & 
        ((Sex == "M") | (Sex == "F")) & 
        ((Region == "AT") | (Region == "DE") | (Region == "UK"))
    ]
)

       user  system elapsed 
      0.073   0.001   0.074
```

**Example #4**

```
system.time(
    DTfull[
        (Age %in% c("TOTAL")) & 
        (Sex %in% c("M", "F")) & 
        (Region %in% c("AT", "DE", "UK"))
    ]
)

       user  system elapsed 
      0.063   0.000   0.064
```

As I have to answer questions similar to the aforementioned one throughout my model, I'm contemplating pursuing a dynamic approach by providing the selection criterions by means of variables. In doing so I have to cope with the case of "NA" values provided, so I came up with an amended solution for example #4.

```
para_age <- c("TOTAL")
para_sex <- c("M", "F")
para_region <- c("AT", "DE", "UK")
            # : some processing
            # : taking place
            # : in between
DTsub <- DTfull[(if (sum(is.na(para_age)) == 0) Age %in% para_age else TRUE) & 
                (if (sum(is.na(para_sex)) == 0) Sex %in% para_sex else TRUE) &
                (if (sum(is.na(para_region)) == 0) Region %in% para_region else TRUE)]
```

The good thing about this, it's working, and I'm receiving the information I'm looking for. The performance varies with the number of variables set to "NA".

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.076   0.003   0.078     para_age = NA
  0.080   0.000   0.081     para_age = NA, para_sex = NA
  0.188   0.142   0.330     para_age = NA, para_sex = NA, para_region = NA
```

The question now, is there a better way of tackling this? What are the drawbacks of my approach?

--Sil68

EDIT: Re-reading my post I might have expressed myself a tick in a misleading manner.

What I'm intending to achieve is not search for NA values in a row/column, but instead sparing a column when searching/filtering if the search criterion is set to NA, ie. all three search criterions (age, sex, region) are non-NA, all three of them are being considered. If say age is set to NA, then a search for sex and region only is getting carried out.

Comment: I don't see anything surprising in the timings you're getting; if you find them tolerable, just go with whatever syntax you like, I'd say. `system.time` is a rough measure compared to proper benchmarking (with the `rbenchmark` or `microbenchmark` packages). I guess you have not read the documentation for `data.table`? A standard way of subsetting is with a key. By the way, I'd suggest converting from wide to long format instead of "transposing".

Comment: @Frank Thanks! -- Actually I've defined a key (as a combination of "age", "sex", and "geo"), but when specifying my search criterions as ".(c("TOTAL"), c("M", "F"), c("AT", "DE", "UK"))" I'm receiving three rows, all with "TOTAL" for "age", "F" for "sex", and the three regions.

Comment: The most efficient route to learning `data.table` is to go through the (rather short) tutorials here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started The right way to "join" on those key values is `DT[J(c("Total"),c("M", "F"), c("AT", "DE", "UK"))]` because `CJ` takes the Cartesian product of those things, looking for all combinations.

Comment: @Frank Brilliant! Thanks again! -- I reckon it's supposed to read "DT[CJ(.." ? And it's even lightning fast!!! :)

Comment: Yep, good catch on my typo :)

Comment: What if the first variable is "NA"? This would the spell "DT[CJ(NA, c("M", "F"), c("AT", "DE", "UK")]. Executing this brings up an error message ("...Error in bmerge...") (well, actually para_age <- NA... DT[CJ(para_age...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78249/discussion-between-frank-and-user4338).